# How to extend session time out in mvc project?

Tags: c#, session, iis, model-view-controller, web-config

In my application session expire automatically in 10 mins. I want to extent it to 30 mins.
I tried in web.config set 30 mins by using below line

```
<sessionState timeout="30"></sessionState>
```

And i changed in iis also but still it auto expire in 10 min. How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: Try `<system.web><sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="30" /></system.web>`

Comment: I tried above line still not working